# How to access non-fingerprinted version of an asset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

To keep things simple, I created a new Rails application today (Rails 4.0.3, Ruby 2.1.1, Phusion Passenger/Nginx for production).

I have an image "logo.png" located in my_app/assets/images/logo.png.

Using the following code, the image displays correctly in development:

```
<img src="/assets/logo.png">
```

In production, I am getting a 404 error when trying to access this asset image file.

I ran the following code on the live production server:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

But still have had no luck.

I can access the image on production with:

```
<%= image_tag "logo.png" %>
```

But I am trying to access the non-fingerprint version of the asset.  The reasoning is that I'm using an HTML template and don't want to have to use all the rails helpers to fix all the paths.

Does anyone know how I can access the image using the /assets/logo.png path rather than using the built in rails helpers?  Thanks.

Comment: can you do one favour, visit your_app.com/assets/logo.png in production and show the logs of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it old school: Put that image into your `/public` folder. All images in asset folders need to be precompiled or they will not be reachable in production. Everything in the `/public` folder is returned without asset pipeline.

So when you have an image in `/public/images/logo.png` than you can download it from `/images/logo.png`